# apache2 and php5: module or filter

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

What the difference between the php5 module (libapache2-mod-php5) and the php5 filter module (libapache2-mod-php5filter) for apache2? Which one should I use in which environment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

libapache2-mod-php5filter doesn't pass all http request methods through to your PHP application - for example, PUT and OPTIONS requests are answered directly by Apache, rather than your PHP application.

I assume that it's limiting the methods that get processed by PHP as a security measure.

libapache2-mod-php5, on the other hand, passes all requests through for processing by PHP.

From https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/5.3.3-7ubuntu1, this message:

"Unless you specifically need filter-module support, you most likely should instead install libapache2-mod-php5"

Comment: See below. Filter modules (mod-php5filter) are completely different from content modules (mod-php5).

Answer (score 2):

**For ease of deployment and configuration**, use `libapache2-mod-php5`.

It really is a lot easier, but causes higher memory usage (as PHP is loaded for each request)

**For scalability**, use `mod_fcgi` and `php-fpm`.

Because it runs a pool of PHP Listeners, then uses FastCGI protocol to communicate between Apache and the Pool of PHPs.

Comment: Is this still the case three years later? Are there any other modules etc. I should consider these days?

Comment: Dunno.  I stopped using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

libapache2-mod-php5filter is used for internal apache php filters. I suppose you could run apps this way, but it's far from recommended as this is not its intention. mod-php5 on the other hand is a content module that generates content (from your php app) and that is what should be used.